# python-openCV module not found error

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I am getting this error

> -"module 'cv2' has no attribute 'version'

when I try to find version of cv2, but my import is executing fine without any error.
I am confused about whether my openCV is working correctly or not?

Comment: See [ask]. It's usually a good idea to show the [mcve] that is related to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your openCV is probably installed in another python version and pylint is having problem identifying. Try to locate where your openCV is installed and manually change it.

Comment: I downloaded it using anaconda so my opencv file is distributed. I am using spyder to run my code?